# Run Celery Task For Past Timestamps

Tags: django, redis, celery

My app was running celery tasks on daily basis. It faced an outage due to some server issues. This made a blank windows in between the tasks. Can somebody let me know if running celery tasks for past timestamps is possible to fill up those gaps?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are using the date now into the task like `timezone.now()`, to patch these past dates you have to receive the date as parameter like this:

```
@app.task
def my_task(date=None):
    if date is None:
        date = timezone.now()
```

then you have to iterate over dates that you missed like this:

```
from dateutil.rrule import DAILY, rrule
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

from_date = timezone.localdate() - relativedelta(days=5)
to_date =  timezone.localdate()

for date in rrule(DAILY, dtstart=from_date, until=to_date:
     my_task.delay(date=date)
```

This example will iterate from 5 days in the past to now and will pass the date as param to the task.

I'm using https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/ in the example.